# Google Chrome Repo (Debian Stable)

Tags: debian, chrome

I need to install google-chrome on debian stable. Is there any way I can add the google's repos and have always the recent version of chrome installed?

Answer (score 8):

From Google's [Linux Repostory Page](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/):

Add Google's key,

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then install package from [the chrome site](https://tools.google.com/chrome), which should add the file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list' that will contain the following,

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

E.g., installing the package from Google *should* just auto-configure your sources.list for you.

Comment: I don't have a browser currently installed and it won't download through links. I just need to add the google repo stuff to my repos and apt-get update and then install the package.

Comment: IMO worth noting that you can also get their key off a keyserver instead, ie: apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys A040830F7FAC5991

Comment: `https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/` returns 404 for me

Answer (score 2):

A new bug has just arisen with this.  The file etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list automatically gets generated and this clobbers the previous version to wipe out your '[arch=amd64]' so then apt-get raises an error.
See
https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/48oje6/linux_how_to_fix_failed_to_fetch/
So the answer to the original question is that there is no fully working method at present but hopefully Google will fix the bug.

Answer (score 2):

@tux-drummer, sorry for a long time to answer. And see more detail hints:

```
$ sudo echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub >> google.pub
$ sudo apt-key add google.pub
OK
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]
...
$ apt-cache search google-chrome
google-chrome-beta - The web browser from Google
google-chrome-stable - The web browser from Google
google-chrome-unstable - The web browser from Google

$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 59.4 MB of archives.
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (76.0.3809.87-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (76.0.3809.87-1) ...
...
```

@Inline, try this code:

```
$ curl -I https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release \
2>/dev/null | grep -Ee "(^content-length|^HTTP)"

HTTP/2 200
content-length: 943
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the problem of the disappearing edit `[arch=amd64]` vanishes. File comments read "automatically configured", but I don't know by what it is automatically configured. So I put a `chattr +i` on `google-chrome.list`.

Comment: The disappearing edit .. vanishes. Does that mean it reappears?